# Eclipse Neon Local Websphere not starting

Tags: java, eclipse, websphere, eclipse-neon, ibm-wdt

Issue: When attempting to start a IBM Websphere server, the console view displays the server as successfully started by displaying the message: server... open for e-business. However, the status of the server in the server view remains in a starting state. Symptom occurs only when Oracle JDK 8 is specified in eclipse.ini. Server status is showed correctly when IBM SDK 8 is specified in eclipse.ini. In both scenarios it is possible to login to the server admin console.

Platform: Windows 7 Professional SP1

IDE: vanilla Eclipse Neon 4.6.1 + plugin mentioned below

Plugin: IBM WebSphere Application Server traditional V8.5x Developer Tools for Neon

Server: IBM Websphere 8.5.5.9

Details configuration files and logs:

When using Oracle JDK 8:

eclipse.ini: `-vm C:/Program Files/Java/jdk8/jre/bin/javaw.exe`

> Eclipse .log eclipse.buildId=4.6.1.M20160907-1200 java.version=1.8.0_102 java.vendor=Oracle Corporation BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=nl_NL Framework arguments: -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product Command-line arguments: -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product

When using IBM JDK 8:

eclipse.ini: `-vm C:/Program Files (x86)/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer-85/java_1.8_64/bin/javaw.exe`

> Eclipse .log eclipse.buildId=4.6.1.M20160907-1200 java.fullversion=JRE 1.8.0 IBM J9 2.8 Windows 7 amd64-64 Compressed References 20160210_289934 (JIT enabled, AOT enabled) J9VM - R28_Java8_SR2_20160210_1617_B289934 JIT - tr.r14.java_20151209_107110.04 GC - R28_Java8_SR2_20160210_1617_B289934_CMPRSS J9CL - 20160210_289934 BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=nl_NL Framework arguments: -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product Command-line arguments: -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product

Websphere server.log (identical for both scenario's: i.e. the same server)

> WebSphere [IBMJAVA7 7.0.8.10 cf051507.01][IBMJAVA8 8.0.2.10 cf091608.04]Platform 8.5.5.9 [BASE 8.5.5.9 cf091608.05] running with process name DPCVOAY005Node12Cell\DPCVOAY005Node12\server1 and process id 285304 Host Operating System is Windows 7, version 6.1 Java version = 1.8.0, Java Runtime Version = pwa6480sr2fp10ifx-20160223_01 (SR2 FP10+IV81318+IV81645+IV81741+IV81716), Java Compiler = j9jit28, Java VM name = IBM J9 VM was.install.root = C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer-85 user.install.root = C:\ws\profiles\ywb-cta-jpa Java Home = C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer-85\java_1.8_64\jre

Comment: Do you use security on WAS level (e.g. when logging into a WAS admin console)? If you do, then you have to configure security options for a server by specifying username and password. I think I had the same scenario as yours and it was because I did not configure security on SOAP connection with WAS...

Comment: Thank you very much! It worked for me! All we have to do it to point Eclipse -vm "<WebSphere folder>/java/bin"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using a non-IBM JDK and working with a local server, can you try the following:

1. Copy `com.ibm.ws.orb_8.5.0.jar` from your `<WAS install>/runtimes` folder into a temporary directory (e.g. `C:\temp\endorsed`)
2. Edit the `eclipse.ini` file in your Eclipse install directory to have the following VM argument `-Djava.endorsed.dirs=<temporary endorsed dir>` (e.g. `-Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\temp\endorsed`)
3. With this change, the RMI and IPC connection type will work. This jar is missing in the non-IBM JDK case and may be the cause of the connection issue

Comment: Thanks this works. One other question does this depends on the specific WAS Version? for example 8.5.5.9.

Comment: This workaround doesn't depend on the WAS Version, your WAS 8, 8.5, and 9 servers should work (if you've installed the tools). The com.ibm.ws.orb_8.5.0.jar contains the missing jar that is used to connect to the server. The server connection mechanism shares common code among all the servers.

Comment: I did this but not helped, any other solution out there ?

Answer (score 1):

open your eclipse.ini file on your eclipse installation file and add -vmargs row above your ibm jdk

```
    -vm 
c:\Program Files\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\java\8.0\bin\javaw.exe
-vmargs
```

Answer (score 0):

What connection type are you using? We are currently seeing problems on using RMI and IPC for non-IBM JDK.  If you happens to be using those connection, can you try switching to use SOAP connection to see if that fixes the problem?

Comment: I've tried all type of connections, both automatically of manually provided (all combinations), that is possible in the server configuration, "Server connection types and administrative ports" (see image). All scenarios do fail.

More specific:

When using connection type IPC:
> Could not create IPC Connector to connect to port 9633, due to
> java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

When using connection type RMI:

> ADMC0017E: Could not create an RMI connector to connect to host
> localhost at port 2809

Comment: When using connection type SOAP:

> The last connection attempt failed with the following exception:
> ADMC0016E: The system cannot create a SOAP connector to connect to
> host localhost at port 8880.

SystemOut.log

[24-11-16 11:30:37:713 CET] 00000001 JMXSoapAdapte A   ADMC0013I: The SOAP connector is available at port 8880

[24-11-16 11:30:37:757 CET] 00000001 IPCConnectorS I   ADMC0070I: The IPC connector is available at port 9633

[24-11-16 11:30:43:054 CET] 00000001 RMIConnectorC A   ADMC0026I: The RMI Connector is available at port 2809